# How to display Nested api data using model class in listview in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am tried to display data in listview.
I have Json Response as below.

```
 [
  {
    "success": 1,
    "subject": [
      {
        "subject_id": "5e32874c714fa",
        "subject_name": "Account",
        "image": "upload/subject/Account.png",
        "active": "1",
        "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
        "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
      },
      {
        "subject_id": "5da9ff659fb7c",
        "subject_name": "Biology",
        "image": "upload/subject/03_logo-1164x484.png",
        "active": "1",
        "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
        "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
      },
      {
        "subject_id": "5da9ff990b1c6",
        "subject_name": "Chemisty",
        "image": "upload/subject/02_logo-1168x490.png",
        "active": "1",
        "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
        "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
      },
      {
        "subject_id": "5de76afbd064e",
        "subject_name": "Computer",
        "image": "upload/subject/07_logo-1169x486.png",
        "active": "1",
        "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
        "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
      },
      {
        "subject_id": "5d788906c431b",
        "subject_name": "Devsatya Paperset March 2020",
        "image": "upload/subject/04_logo-1174x491.png",
        "active": "1",
        "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
        "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

as above response i create a model class as below

```
 // To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final subjectByUser = subjectByUserFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<SubjectByUser> subjectByUserFromJson(String str) =>
    List<SubjectByUser>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((x) => SubjectByUser.fromJson(x)));

String subjectByUserToJson(List<SubjectByUser> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class SubjectByUser {
  SubjectByUser({
    required this.success,
    required this.subject,
  });

  int success;
  List<Subject> subject;

  factory SubjectByUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SubjectByUser(
        success: json["success"],
        subject:
            List<Subject>.from(json["subject"].map((x) => Subject.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "subject": List<dynamic>.from(subject.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Subject {
  Subject({
    required this.subjectId,
    required this.subjectName,
    required this.image,
    required this.active,
    required this.standardId,
    required this.mediumId,
  });

  String subjectId;
  String subjectName;
  String image;
  String active;
  String standardId;
  String mediumId;

  factory Subject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Subject(
        subjectId: json["subject_id"],
        subjectName: json["subject_name"],
        image: json["image"],
        active: json["active"],
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        mediumId: json["medium_id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "subject_id": subjectId,
        "subject_name": subjectName,
        "image": image,
        "active": active,
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "medium_id": mediumId,
      };
}
```

I write below code, now how can i display subjects data  like subjectName, image, etc in list view?
in print i can get the subject name on index 3.

```
Future getUserSubject(List subject) async {
    final subjectUrl =
        "$baseUrl/subject/get_by_user_plan?user_id=609cab2cd5b6c&order_id=1620889722609cd07a601af469889697609cab2cd5b6c&standard_id=5d1594e283e1a&medium_id=5d15938aa1344";
    

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(subjectUrl));
    final subjects = response.body;
    final decodedData = jsonDecode(subjects);
    SubjectByUserModel subjectByUserModel =
        SubjectByUserModel.fromJson(decodedData);
    print(subjectByUserModel.subject?[2].subjectName);
    
  }
```

I put all codes in separate file also view

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: subjectByUserModel.subject ?? 0,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      print(subjectByUserModel.subject?[index].subjectName);
      print(subjectByUserModel.subject?[index].standardId); // so on
      // Now you can build any widget for per subject.
      // like card, listTile or simple text.
      return Text('');
    });
```

Comment: thank you sir for your answer.  but i have all codes in separate files so how can i pass the getUserSubject data to a view file. i am new in flutter  so please help me.

Comment: If it helps please mark it as answer, as it will help others.

Comment: @DhavalChaudhari If your file is under one parent and had different children in it (like a tree), you can use the Inherited widget to access the data, Is it what are you looking for?

Comment: i have api_manager.dart file wich have all get and post functions which includes getUserSubject function,SubjectByUserModel model class in Subject_model.dard file, and  SubjectWidget statefull widget in SubjectWidget.dart file wich in i have to display the data of subjects.

Comment: Use any architecture pattern or state management, It will help you how to keep code tidy and separated and pass data between them, you can watch this playlist from resocoder. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjE2IDphA_U&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iYGE_khpXRdJkJEp9WOech

Comment: Happy to help , Good luck.